# Why does inotifywait stop working consistently after a git checkout on the files it's watching?

Tags: bash, git, sh, inotify, inotifywait

I am running `inotifywait` on a directory of files:

```
inotifywait --quiet --monitor  \
  --event modify \
  --event moved_to \
  --event moved_from \
  --event move \
  --event unmount \
  --event create \
  --format '%w' /path/to/*.json | \
while read FILE; do
  echo "$FILE was changed."
done
```

This works well until I run `git checkout [some existing branch name]`. After that, `inotifywait` stops responding to files that `git` updated when checking out the branch (That is, is stops responding to files that are different between the two branches).

Why does `inotifywait` stop responding to these files? Is there a way for it to re-see those files?

Comment: Don't point `inotifywait` at the individual files, point it at the *directory*. `git` replaces the files so they no longer exist, so there no longer are any events happening on them.

Comment: Remember that when you get a file handle, it points to an inode, not a directory entry. If you create a new and different file with the same name, it's still a *new and different* file; there's no continuity or relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inotifywait --event create /path/to/*.json` doesn't work *at all*, because an already-existing file can't have a `create` event, and `/path/to/*.json` is replaced with a list of already-existing filenames by your shell before `inotifywait` is even started; any file that doesn't exist won't be included, and when `inotifywait` `open()`s the existing files, it'll get only the preexisting copies, and thus won't even see any new files created under the same name in the future.

Follow the directory instead:

```
inotifywait --quiet --monitor  \
  --event modify \
  --event moved_to \
  --event moved_from \
  --event move \
  --event unmount \
  --event create \
  --format '%w' /path/to | \
while IFS= read -r file; do
  [[ $file = *.json ]] || continue  # ignore any non-*.json files
  echo "$file was changed."
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I ended up using `while read PATH ACTION FILE; do...` along with your approach. I didn't realize about `inotifywait` pointing to an inode; I appreciate your detailed explanation in the comments above, as well as your answer here. I understand `inotifywait` better now, thanks to your explanation.

Comment: Note that the above isn't particularly safe if the file name can contain spaces; better to put it at the end of the input line. (Better than that to use NUL delimiters to allow even names with literal newlines to be correctly handled, but I don't recall whether `inotifywait` supports them).